# Animate a button with jquery

Tags: jquery, button, popup, jquery-animate

Could somebody help me to animate my search button with the help of jquery or javascript.Whenever a user hovers my search button,i want search box to appear(and stay visible while a user stil searched something there),but whenever a mouse is away from that search button or a search box, this little box should dissapear.

```
<div class = "searchBox">
    <p id = "paragraph"><input type = "text" name = "serachBar"/>
    <input type = "button" value = "szukaj" name = "search"/>
    </p>
    <div id = "searchButton"><a href = "#">Search</a></div>
</div>
```

css

```
body{
background-color:rgb(138,187,129);

#searchButton{
position:fixed;
border:1px solid rgb(255,255,255);
border-top:none;
width:80px;
height:30px;
top:0px;
right:60px;
border-radius:0px 0px 3px 3px;
background:rgb(30,114,41);
}
#searchButton :hover{
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
#searchButton a{
text-decoration:none;
font-size:20px;
font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
text-align:center;
color:white;
padding:0;
margin:0;
display:block;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

.searchBox p{
position:fixed;
border-bottom:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
border-radius:2px;
box-shadow:0 1px 2px 2px #1F0000;
-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 2px 2px #1F0000;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px 2px #1F0000;
border-top:none;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
width:200px;
height:50px;
top:0;
right:0;
margin:0;
visibility:hidden;
font-size:15px;
font-family:"Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
color:white;
}
```

Comment: You should post the code that is relevant to your problem - Most of us here don't like to read irrelevant code.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick answer really. You may need to edit this to suit exact what you need but i believe the sort of jquery you are after is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit, #searchField').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $('#searchField').fadeIn(400);    
    }); 
    $('#submit, #searchField').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $('#searchField').fadeOut(400);    
    }); 
});
```

html:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="searchField" id="searchField"/>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3yRcu/) too

Comment: It might be better to just bind the mouseenter/mouseleave events to `.searchBox`

Comment: Ok,maybe if i do it with javascript,do I need to write to functions to have that box pop up and hide again,or I can do it somehow in a simpler way?Do I need to make smth like onmouseover="function1()" and onmouseout="function2()"?

Comment: The code written above makes it hide and show automatically when certain elements are hovered over or the mouse leaves them. The code there works for what you were after in your original question i believe. At least that's what i got from your question! haha

Answer (score 0):

So this is one way to do it.  Just set a div outside of the search box and the search button. Then set a mouseenter and mouseleave event.  You will also need to check if any text has been entered.  heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bgs7D/

```
 var $divContainer = $('#divContainer'),
 $txtSearch = $('#txtSearch'),
 $btnSearch = $('#btnSearch');

$txtSearch.hide();

$divContainer.on('mouseenter',function(){
    $txtSearch.show();
});

$divContainer.on('mouseleave',function(){
    if($txtSearch.val()==''){
        $txtSearch.hide();
    }
});
```

and the html:

```
<div id= "divContainer"> 
<input id="txtSearch" type ="text" ></input>
<input id="btnSearch" type = "button" value="Search" ></input> 
</div>
```